# Extends the tabactivity class through the custom class inthe android

Tags: interface, multiple-inheritance

This is the current code:

```
public class Ticket_Tabs extends TabActivity {
// TabActivity  is the inbuilt class of android

public class navigation_drawer_class extends Activity
//This is my another class

public interface navigation_drawer_interface extends Serializable
{
    navigation_drawer_class obj=new navigation_drawer_class();
    
}//THIS is interface
```

I expect,

```
public class Ticket_Tabs extends TabActivity,navigation_drawer_class  {
```

How can I achieve this? I am new to Android. I am just trying to show the navigation drawer to the TabActivity.
I already tried diffrent ways but i an failed to implement. Please suggest me solution if any.I also read may tpoics related to this on stack overflow but I cant understand. So please help me.
Thanks in advance

```
public class Ticket_Tabs extends TabActivity implements Serializable  {

//I tried this but not working @@Taslim
```

Comment: Just a side note: Serializable is an interface.. implement it, don't extend it. Also, you can't extend more than one class.

Comment: I tried ,not worked .Please suggest other solution.